# Overwrite targets post build event of another targets file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, target, overwrite, post-build-event

I have a NuGet package that adds to my C# projects a targets file with that content for the post build event.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="ThisIsMyTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="ThisIsMyCommand.exe"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

In less than 1% of the projects, I don't need this command, I need another command to be executed. Is it possible with the targets files to suspend a target from another targets file?

Something like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="ThisIsMyRareTarget" Overwrite="ThisIsMyTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="ThisIsMyRareCommand.exe"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I don't want to split my NuGet package only for the 1% of the project.

Comment: You should be able to add both targets in every project and then use a property that's only defined in your rare 1% projects to set the [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-element-msbuild#attributes-and-elements) attribute on each.

Comment: Hi DangerSchwob, any upadate for this issue?

Comment: Hi Perry, your concept sounds interesting, but I have some other conditions around, that makes it difficult. I'm checking if I could use a modified version of your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Overwrite targets post build event of another targets file

**Actually**, if you want to use multiple target files into nuget package and then switch between different target files depending on your needs, you cannot get what you want.

And as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) said, when you want to add a target file into a project by nuget, you should make sure the name of the target file is the same as the name of the nuget package so that it will work.

So you can only use one target file named `<package_id>.targets` and set a `condidtion` in it to distinguish which project environment to use.

**Solution**

**1)** please put these all in your `<package_id>.targets` file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Flag></Flag>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="ThisIsMyTarget" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Flag)'!='true'">
        <Exec Command="ThisIsMyCommand.exe"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="ThisIsMyRareTarget" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Flag)'=='true'">
        <Exec Command="ThisIsMyRareCommand.exe"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**2)** then you pack your nuget project and when you install your nuget in other projects(**less than 1% of the projects**), you should define the property **Flag** to `true` on the end of the `xxx.csproj` file like this:

[image]

**And** less than 1% projects can use `ThisIsMyRareTarget.exe`. In other 99% projects, you should not define Flag property in `xxx.csproj` and it will automatic capture `ThisIsMyCommand.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

All the credit goes to @Perry Quian-MSFT. He had right concept.

I have created 2 targets files / NuGet packages.

The standard package using this targets file.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="ThisIsMyTarget" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(DontUseStandardCommand)'!='true'">
        <Exec Command="ThisIsMyCommand.exe"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The rare case targets file looks like this.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="ThisIsMyRareTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="ThisIsMyRareCommand.exe"/>
    </Target>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DontUseStandardCommand>true</DontUseStandardCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This is working fine in my setup, also independent of the order of the import targets files in the project file.